# How do I use a wildcard with U-SQL's EXTRACT for all files in a storage account path?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to use the following to extract data from a set of files in U-SQL:

```
@elevations =
    EXTRACT TileId    string,
            Elevation double
    FROM "wasb://elevations@testaccount.blob.core.windows.net/*"
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent:true);
```

but U-SQL doesn't seem to like "*".  How do you do wildcarding with U-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "{*}" syntax, ala:

```
@elevations =
    EXTRACT TileId    string,
            Elevation double
    FROM "wasb://elevations@testaccount.blob.core.windows.net/{*}"
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent:true);
```